# Checking cisco network device rules programmatically

Tags: network-programming, firewall, snmp, cisco, cisco-ios

I want to be able to show (by device) open/blocked status for a given protocol between two devices/ports on a network.  In other words, I need to output a list of network devices (firewalls & switches) between Server A and Server B and indicate whether the request should (according to each device's rules) be allowed through or blocked.

I'm starting with the Cisco networking devices, which are centrally managed by Cisco's Security Manager (CSM) application (version 4.2).  I'm new to network management automation programming and want to make sure I'm not overlooking an obvious best way to handle this.

So far it's looking like I'll need to periodically export and ETL device rules out of CSM (they have a perl script that I can call to do this I believe) and into a separate database, then write some custom SQL code to determine which devices on a route between two hosts/ports will allow or block traffic of the given protocol?

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I think you can run a TCL script inside the Cisco equipments do collect the necessary information and transfer it to a central server, form there import it to a database and then correlate that information.

Hope that helps you in your work.